# Samsung Resources$NotFoundException in Editor$SuggestionsPopupWindow.initContentView()

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

Crash occurs on Samsung devices (J7 and S7) running Android 7.0.

I've built a tiny test app and can reproduce the crash. Single `Activity` that extends `Activity` (not `AppCompatActivity`), simple layout containing a single `EditText` with `inputType="text"`. **Target SDK is 8.**

When positioning the cursor in the `EditText` and typing, words are suggested and words are underlined. Click on some of the underlined words or complete editing in the `EditText` and then return to the `EditText`. After entering some data and clicking around inside the `EditText`, the app will crash with this stacktrace:

```
06-01 18:56:37.990 10339-10339/sharpmind.de.samsungtest W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
06-01 18:56:37.991 10339-10339/sharpmind.de.samsungtest D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
06-01 18:56:37.992 10339-10339/sharpmind.de.samsungtest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: sharpmind.de.samsungtest, PID: 10339
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:202)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2970)
at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1986)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:425)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:378)
at android.widget.Editor$SuggestionsPopupWindow.initContentView(Editor.java:3704)
at android.widget.Editor$PinnedPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:3395)
at android.widget.Editor$SuggestionsPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:3683)
at android.widget.Editor.replace(Editor.java:432)
at android.widget.Editor$3.run(Editor.java:2359)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

**With target SDK set to 14, the crash does not occur.**

If I disable the autocorrect and word suggestions (which isn't that easy to do on a Samsung device), the crash also does not occur. But this makes my users really really angry, so it isn't a viable solution.

---

**Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
}
```

**Layout:**

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:minHeight="200dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```